# Django annotate usage over an model instance other than query item

Tags: django, django-models, annotate

I have a query such that

```
em =Employer.objects.filter(id=1).annotate(overall_value = Sum('companyreview__overallRating'))

em[0].overall_value
```

As you see I want to sum of `overallRating` field of all `companyreview` objects whose `employer` has `id = 1`.

The query above does what I want but I am sure that there is a way to get the sum from an `Employer` instance.

How can I implement this query like

```
em =Employer.objects.get(id=1)
rate = em.companyreview_set.all().annotate(overall_value = Sum('overallRating'))
rate.overall_value
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Please paste your simplified models to get a good answer.  Are you using one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: As you already guessed that it was one-to-many. Thanks for your detailed answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate`:

```
e.companyreview_set.aggregate(overall_value = Sum('overall_rating'))
```

For:

```
class Employer(models.Model): 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CompanyReview(models.Model): 
     employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
     overall_rating = models.IntegerField()
```